# Objective C - Calling UICollectionview using navigation push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm implementing UICollectionView without storyboard or xib files.
Currently my firstviewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller and calls collectionviewcontroller when button is clicked.

Here is my code in firstviewcontroller.m

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20;

CollectionViewController *ivc = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
```

However I don't want to have layout code in here. I want to have it somewhere in collectionviewcontroller.m. Probably in viewDidLoad I guess?

But I have to have the layout to initialize collectionviewcontroller in order to push view.
Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag one laguage at a time Objective C or Swift..so user can understand in which language they have to give answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set FlowLayout after pushing viewController like below code, Let me know you if this still not fix your issue.

```
@implementation UICollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20;

    [self setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing.. What I want is to move the layout code into collectionviewcontroller.m to make it look consistent (keep all UICollectionView related code in one place)

Comment: You mean add another layout code? So I would have two layouts (one before push view, one in viewDidLoad)?

Comment: remove layout code which you added before push and add one only in viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok. Then how should I call collectionviewcontroller for navigation push? Segue?

Comment: Pass layout nill